# jQuery data from $.get isn't available by other functions

Tags: jquery, get, global-variables

hi all i've got this bit of code but it keeps kicking out 'undefined;

```
var projectID = $.getUrlVar('id');
var projectname;

$.get('functions.php?func=projectname&id='+projectID, function(data) {
    projectname = data;
    alert(projectname+'<- see nice content');
});

alert(projectname+'<- no content :(');
```

how can i make "projectname" available outside that one get function?

(i did notice, when running that code actually, that the no content alert popped up before the nice content. is the .get the last thing on the page that runs? is this why its all blank? coz the variable doesnt appear to be set yet?

thanks

Comment: suggest you read the spec in details, especially the part of `success` callback function, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AJAX runs asynchronously (that is what first `A` in `AJAX` acronym stands for).

So you have 2 solutions for your issue:

1. Don't try to access the data outside the anonymous function. Do all the work there (the best solution)
2. Change your `$.get` to `$.ajax` and set its `async` option to false (terrible solution)

Comment: Your second point is almost not worth mentioning for fear it will be used :P

Comment: In case the OP doesn't know what asynchronous means, the first alert is not executed until a response is received from the server. Meanwhile, the rest of his code after $.get continues executing. That is, the $.get and the second alert statement are not _synchronized_ with each other... thus they are *a*synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your second alert actually executes before the AJAX request has finished.

The "A" in "AJAX" stands for Asynchronous.

Any functionality relying on data returned from an AJAX request should only be implemented within or called by the `success` callback

Comment: Hehe, the same notice about `AJAX` abbreviation nature :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because the XHR is asynchronous, you can't like that.

Handle all code as a *descendent function*, deeper on the callstack with an origination from the complete callback (where `projectname` will have the correct value assigned).